# How to manually partially apply a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

I'm having trouble understanding how the following code works. I'm trying to follow the parser example found [here](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html#parsec). I have used `ReadP` before and want to get a more in-depth understanding of how parsers work. My question isn't specific to parsers, rather to how function application in Haskell works. Here's the code:

```
module NanoParsec where

import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a,String)] }

runParser :: Parser a -> String -> a
runParser m s =
    case parse m s of
        [(res, [])] -> res
        [(_, rs)]   -> error "Parser did not consume entire stream."
        _           -> error "Parser error."

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \s ->
    case s of
        []     -> []
        (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)]
```

I understand the imports aren't needed yet. When I load this into `ghci`, it works as expected:

```
Prelude> runParser item "m"
'm'
Prelude> runParser item "ms"
*** Exception: Parser did not consume entire stream.
```

So no surprise here. What I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is how `runParser` is applied to `item`. Partially applying `runParser` to `item` yields a function of type `String -> Char`:

```
Parser> :t runParser item
runParser item :: String -> Char
```

Here's how I'm trying to desugar/apply `runParser` to `item` manually:

```
runParser item 
runParser Parser (\s -> ...)
(\m -> \s -> case parse m s of ...) Parser (\s -> ...)
```

This is where I'm stuck. If I replace `m` with the function within `Parser`, I get `parse parse s`, which seems wrong to me. How do I apply `runParser` to `item` so I end up with a function of type `String -> Char`? I feel like my [attempt at desugaring](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/10/how-to-desugar-haskell-code.html) are off.

**EDIT**: I wrongly stated that `item` is applied to `runParser`; I confused the function and variable here.

Comment: Your nomenclature is a little confused: you don’t apply `item` to `runParser`, you apply `runParser` to `item`. Functions are applied to their arguments, not the other way around.

Comment: Okay, I have only recently looked into lambda calculus, I'll rephrase my question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you started in the right direction:

```
runParser item
= { definition of item }
runParser (Parser $ \s -> case s of ...)
= { definition of runParser }
(\m s -> case parse m s of ...) (Parser $ \s -> case s of ...)
= { substitute argument for m everywhere }
(\s -> case parse (Parser $ \s -> case s of ...) s of ...)
= { definition of parse }
(\s -> case (\(Parser f) -> f) (Parser $ \s -> case s of ...) s of ...)
= { substitute argument for f everywhere }
(\s -> case (\s -> case s of ...) s of ...)
= { substitute argument for s everywhere }
(\s -> case (case s of ...) of ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! One little question: How do you come to the definition of `parse`? using `:t parse` in ghci yields `parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]`.

Comment: I think, I got it; `parse` takes a `Parser` and yields the value inside the `Parser`; the new type and the value of the field are basically the same

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified my code, it uses pattern matching instead of record syntax. This might be easier to understand for others:

```
module NanoParsec where

import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

-- newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a,String)] }
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])

runParser :: Parser a -> String -> a
runParser (Parser p) s =
    case p s of
        [(res, [])] -> res
        [(_, rs)]   -> error "Parser did not consume entire stream."
        _           -> error "Parser error."

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \s ->
    case s of
        []     -> []
        (c:cs) -> [(c,cs)]
```